# How would one change the way that a mesh deforms, such that a specific area does whilst everything else is left intact?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, rigging, transforms, surface-deform

Practicing rigging and I had added an armature bone to a box with a slit in it to simulate rudimentary lip movement. However, it didn't just move the lips, it also deformed the box itself. I was wondering if there was a way I could change the deform modifier such that only the region where the slit exists deforms but everything else doesn't.

Drew a diagram of it:
[image: The kind of deform I want vs. the kind of deform I'm getting.]

Comment: please add blend file, we have no idea how you did setup this and how you did weight paint....thx

Comment: Add a few more bones that follow the box shape. The new bones will limit the influence of the existing bones and stop the deformation. The weights define how much influence each bone has. As an example, look at the [Rigify face rig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT8U9.png). The bones around the mouth deform the mouth while the cheek & jaw bones stop the deformation of the mouth and keep the rest of the face stable. The same applies to the eyes and forehead, and so on.